# Executing "gsutil" command、"WARNING: Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way. This will fail in a future version of macOS...."

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

I installed google-cloud SDK, and upgraded.
When I execute gsutil command, the message is shown twice that

> WARNING: Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe
>   way. This will fail in a future version of macOS. Set the
>   LIBRESSL_REDIRECT_STUB_ABORT=1 in the environment to force this into
>   an error.

I want to resolve this message that occurs every time I execute "gsutil" command.

My Environment is described blew.

```
Mac OS 10.15.4

python -V
Python 3.8.2

gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 287.0.0
bq 2.0.56
core 2020.03.30

gsutil 4.49
openssl version
LibreSSL 2.8.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a [Github Issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/952) in Google's gsutil repository reporting the same issue you posted. Currently there is no update therein so I would recommend posting your situation there too so that the development team could address it for every user in the same situation.

By the while, I also researched for a fix although I was unable to find it. The best would be to ignore the warning until a solution is posted on the Github issue.